Do different shells cause the scrap hammer to do different damage?
With the scrap hammer skill, you can attach a shell to your fork to turn it into a heavy attacking hammer, which deals considerably more poise and hp damage with a slower attack speed. Do different shell types do different amounts of damage? If so, is there a shell stat associated with the goodness of the hammer?

It seems like larger shells do more damage and attack more slowly but would want to do some more testing on this
